# sfdx force:package:version:create The provided package ID '0Hoxxxxx' is invalid

Tags: salesforcedx, unlocked-package

I've just recently started getting an error:

> The provided package ID '0Ho1C0000004C9wSAE' is invalid.

when trying to run `sfdx force:package:version:create`.

This was previously working exactly as I'm doing it now (I've released multiple versions; haven't made changes to `sfdx-project.json`).

If I run `sfdx force:pacakge:list` I see my package version listed out.

```
Namespace Prefix  Name          Id                  Alias         Description                            Type
────────────────  ────────────  ──────────────────  ────────────  ─────────────────────────────────────  ────────
VARS              env-vars      0Ho1C0000004C9wSAE  env-vars      Salesforce Enviroment Vars Management  Unlocked
VARS              vars-encrypt  0Ho1C0000004CA6SAM  vars-encrypt  Salesforce Enviroment Vars Management  Managed
```

Why all of a sudden would it stop working?

Answer (score 7):

The issue is happening because i was targeting the wrong hub-org.

Comment: Thanks, had the same problem

Comment: Hi, what do you mean by you were targeting the wrong hub-org? I'm facing the same error and unable to resolve it. Could you please detail out the steps used to resolve this?